# Не работает вывод

Tags: java

Здравствуйте! Появилась проблемка:

Работаю с двумерными массивами, код рабочей зоны приведен ниже:

```
 Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
            String str;
            while (sc.hasNext()) {
                Random r1 = new Random();
                Random r2 = new Random();
                int r1i = r1.nextInt(5);
                int r2i = r2.nextInt(4);
                System.out.println(r1i + " " + r2i);

                str = sc.nextLine();
                System.out.println("Ввод: " + str);
                if (r1i == 0 && r2i == 0) {
                    ner[r1i][r2i] = 1;
                    if(ners[r1i][r2i].equalsIgnoreCase("f")){
                        ners[r1i][r2i] = ners[r1i][r2i].replace("f", str);
                        ners[r1i][r2i] = str;
                    }
                } else {
                    continue;
                }
                if (str.equalsIgnoreCase("test1")) {
                    System.out.println(" Вывод чисел");
                    for (int i = 0; i < j; i++) {
                        System.out.print(ner[i][1]);
                        for (int c = 0; c < k; c++) {
                            System.out.print(" " + ner[i][c]);
                        }
                        System.out.println("  ");
                    }
                    System.out.println("==============");
                }
                if (str.equalsIgnoreCase("tests")) {
                    System.out.println(" Вывод строк");
                    for (int i = 0; i < j; i++) {
                        System.out.print(ners[i][1]);
                        for (int c = 0; c < k; c++) {
                            System.out.print(" " + ners[i][c]);
                        }
                        System.out.println("  ");
                    }
                    System.out.println("==============");
                }
                if (str.equalsIgnoreCase("br")) {
                    break;
                }
            }
```

Главное ввод вроде бы работает... Но вроде бы и нет)
Ввожу test, а результата - нет( 
А должно было вывести двумерный массив... То же самое и с командой tests и br.Почему же так?)

Comment: Именно этот код нужен, VladID, проблему с командами test1 tests удалось решить, перетаскиванием команд чуть выше, но теперь не работает сам ввод символов и переменных в матрицу

Comment: @IvanS: Неужели нельзя упростить? Если убрать `Random` и заменить фиксированными значениями, всё работает нормально? Если убрать `System.out.println("===============")`, всё работает нормально?

Comment: Так если мы уберем рандом, то у нас матрица не запомнится, рандом генерирует какие-то цифры, и так матрица и заполнится)) Честно говоря, не знаю как заменить...

Comment: @IvanS: Ну, а разве для примера существенно то, что матрица заполняется именно случайными числами? Это может быть существенно для вашей программы, но для расследования проблемы это (наверняка) не интересно.

Comment: Да нет же)Смотрите, мы вводим(ввод бесконечный) букву, одна матрица запоминает эту букву, то есть элемент матрицы запоминает ее, в другой матрице мы берем и 0 меняем на 1, только меняем элемент с тем же "номером" как и в матрице строк.То есть если String[1][2] = строка, то и int[1][2] = 1, зачем я этот рандом добавил) Случайные числа выбирают вот эти номера в скобочках квадратных

Comment: @IvanS: Давайте я попробую в последний раз объяснить.

Смотреть весь ваш код и разбираться в его логике _всем_ лень. То, что вам для внутренних целей нужен рандом, **не имеет к вашей проблеме с выводом никакого отношения**. Логика отношения между матрицами для решения вопроса не интересна и лишь отвлекает, так как приходится думать над тем, происходит проблема из-за этого кода или нет.

Попробуйте составить **минимальный** пример, воспроизводящий проблему, то есть такой пример, из которого нельзя выкинуть **ни одной команды**, и в котором проявляется та же самая проблема с выводом.

Comment: Вот минимальный пример: Есть матрица int[1][6] a; Е1 нужно заполнить числами, которые мы введем с клавиатуры.И если мы введем с клавиатуры слово go,то матрица выводится.Неожиданно для себя, понял, что не смогу сделать даже этот простой пример, @VladD, не поможете?) В коде есть рабочие участки вывода матрицы, как раз где написано вывод чисел, если они чем то помогут, конечно...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У вас ввод с клавиатуры? По идее, не должно сработать, так как начальный `sc.hasNext()` будет ждать, пока что-то не будет введено.

Попробуйте обойтись без него, выход сделайте по введению ключевого слова.

Вот пример: http://pastebin.com/xAJCgith (знатоки Java пусть меня поправят).

Comment: Ввод с клавиатуры..да Пошаманю потом,вроде то что нужно!!! Спасибо!

Comment: @IvanS: Пожалуйста. Надеюсь, не слишком неидиоматично (Java — не мой профиль).